# Javascript: setInterval function not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code. Interval  is set to 10sec.

```
(function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        disp_log(); 
        setInterval(function () {
            disp_log();
        }, 10 * 1000);

        function disp_log() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                "type" : "GET", 
                "url" : "/get_log/", 
                "dataType" : "json", 
                "cache" : false, 
                "success" : function(json) { 
                    data=""
                    for(var j = 0; j < json.length; j++) { 
                        data+="<tr><td>"+json[j]+"</td></tr>"
                    } 
                    $("#log").html(data);
                } 
            })(jQuery); 
        }
    }); 
})(django.jQuery);
```

But refreshing dosen't happen. Can someone plz tell why?

Comment: Are you sure that your AJAX call is working, and that it is accessing the page you want? Remember AJAX is * asynchronous* so it doesn't matter if you call it every 10 seconds, it may take longer than that to find a response.

Comment: And are you sure the data change and the file isn't cached ?

Comment: The whole javascript file is evaluated before anything is run, @ppeterka, it's not a problem with positioning :)

Comment: Add breakpoints, debug, so many things could have been wrong here but only you can tell if the success function is called.

Comment: @niaccurshi that's why I didn't pu tthat as an answer.. If I was a JS engine - I'd be broken it turns out :)

Comment: My ajax request works fine. The page loads fine initially. After that it dosent refresh. Yes the data keeps changing. I'll try to put a debug pt n check

Comment: @arjun i have updated my answer with all the correction please do check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to do here is debug. First of all work out if you are getting *any* code back at all. You can do this by using....

```
"success" : function(json) { 
    console.log(json);
    //or..
    alert(json);
}
```

If they don't return anything, then your AJAX request is the problem, not your setInterval code.

However on your setInterval code, you should know that the ajax call could take any time to load, so you shouldn't just keep running it. A better way would be to use setTimeout....

```
setTimeout(disp_log,10*1000);
```

Then, inside your success function, put that same code in again...

```
"success" : function(json) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        disp_log()
    },10*1000);
}
```

This will ensure that your code keeps running 10 seconds after the last time the data was successful. There are other issues to consider (how you keep the script running if the ajax call fails, for example) but this will ensure you don't end up getting out of sync with your server requests!

Comment: Placing the setTimeout function inside "success" did the trick. Thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

Use it as below.

```
setInterval(disp_log, 10 * 1000);
```

if you function is in global then use it as

```
setInterval("disp_log()", 10 * 1000);
```

also you don't need `(jQuery)` after end of ajax call.

**And more important** you have `(function($){`  and `$(document).ready(function() {`.
You don't need it because both are same use either one.

**Working Tested Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        disp_log(); 
        setInterval(disp_log, 10 * 1000);

        function disp_log()
        {
            $.ajax({ 
                "type" : "GET", 
                "url" : "/get_log/", 
                "dataType" : "json", 
                "cache" : false, 
                "success" : function(json)
                { 
                    var data;
                    for(var j = 0; j < json.length; j++)
                    { 
                        data+="<tr><td>"+json[j]+"</td></tr>"
                    } 
                    $("#log").html(data);
                } 
            }); 
        }
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: This won't change anything.

Comment: @user1737909 i know there are more errors in OP code but main concern was about not looping periodically so i cleared that first and BTW you can test it function test() {}
var refreshId = setInterval(test, 5000); this will work too...so down-vote for that is really silly..

Comment: This is one of the things working fine in the original code. I agree it's the same (and it's easier) but that's not an actual solution.

Comment: @user1737909 if u see there are $(document).ready(function() {  and other jQuery initialization code too...

Comment: Placing the setTimeout function inside "success" did the trick. Thanx :)

Comment: @arjun if you want to set when its first return success response then its fine but it will not be added if you want to setTimeout no matter if first ajax call fail for some reason..

Comment: @user1737909 what do you mean.?

Comment: `setInterval("abc()", delay);` uses eval for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here : `$.ajax` does not return you something to call jQuery on. No need for that `(jQuery)`

Answer (score 0):

### PROBLEM MAY BE OF THE BROWSER

I had a problem using this `setInterval()` function, but later I found it was the problem of my mozilla. When I tried to run in Chrome, it was perfect.

Comment: What is the Problem below? This doesn't look like a real answer.